# How to exit PowerShell.exe inside of CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

In the command prompt, entering `PowerShell.exe` will start a PowerShell interactive prompt inside of `cmd`.

How can one exit this and return to `cmd.exe`?  Neither `ctrl+c`, `exit()`, nor the `break` button work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Ctrl-Break` works.

`exit()` might work, but calling functions with parentheses is not PowerShell syntax, so it's trying to use `()` as a function parameter, but `()` is not anything in PowerShell so it's that which generates the error message. `exit(1)` works, because `(1)` is a valid expression itself which evaluates to `1` so this is the same as `exit 1`, and this command sets the %ERRORLEVEL% return value in the cmd environment.

It's described in `help about_Language_Keywords`:

> **Exit**
>
> Causes Windows PowerShell to exit a script or a Windows PowerShell instance.
>
> When you run 'powershell.exe -File ', you can only set the %ERRORLEVEL% variable to a value other than zero by using the exit statement.

- [help link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords#exit)

Comment: It somehow doesn't work, if I run PowerShell from inside a `*.bat` file:
`PowerShell "ForEach($P in Get-Process steamwebhelper) {$P.ProcessorAffinity=1}; exit"`

After this command it hangs up. Additionally, I run it from Cygwin terminal and if I don't Ctrl-C fast enough, the terminal freezes.

Answer (score 16):

The correct command is `exit`, this will exit the current PowerShell prompt and return you to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Can you please tell, after powershell closes ,how can I exit form cmd.exe through batch job. Basically I am writing a batch jon to trucate the data from file.But the scrip is not closing   cmd window.                                                                                
 @echo off
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "Clear-Content -Force E:\Logs\pgbouncer.log;
exit %ERRORLEVEL%"

Comment: @Madhu add Exit to the bottom of your batch job. So Exit in powershell and Exit in the batch.  hth

Answer (score 1):

`stop-process -Id $PID`
to close the powershell window completely.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this working inside a ".ps1" file was:

```
[System.Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

type cmd in powershell command line, eg

PS C:\Users\ziyati\Gitter> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ziyati\Gitter>

that all !